# ¿Cómo obtener la posición de una fila de una tabla HTML con PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un plugin para wordpress, y para poder eliminar artículos de una tabla necesito obtener la posición de la fila correspondiente.

Mi código HTML:

```
<table id="tablaComienzo" name="tablaComienzo" class = "wp-list-table widefat fixed striped pages">
    <thead>
        <th>Nombre Api</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Documento</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<form method='post'>

    <?php
    $contador = 0;
    foreach($lista_info as $key=>$value){
        $valor_api = $value["Api_"];
        $valor_pass = $value["Password_"]; 
        $valor_doc = $value["Documento_"];
        $info_id = $value["Id_"]; 
    
    
      
    echo "<tr name='filas[]'><td>".$valor_api."</td><td>".$valor_pass."</td><td>".$valor_doc."</td><td name='info'>".$info_id."</td><td><button type='submit' name='btnEliminar' id='$contador' class=´btn btn-danger´>Eliminar</td></tr>";
    $contador++;
  }
?>

</form>
    
</tbody>
</table>
```

Para eliminar, necesito obtener la posición de la fila seleccionada. Mi código PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["btnEliminar"])){
      echo "<script>alert('Entra')</script>";
           
         
           echo var_dump($lista_info[$posicion]["Id_"]);
    
            global $wpdb;
            $tabla = 'tabla_valores_doc';
            $wpdb->delete($tabla, array("Id_"=>$id));
    
    }
    ?>
```

Lo he intentado de varias maneras, pero ninguna funciona. ¿Cómo se puede obtener la posición de una fila de una tabla por medio de PHP? Gracias.

Comment: Con posicion te refieres a la ID de la fila ?? O que te refieres con posicion?

Comment: Hola. Me refiero a su posición dentro de la tabla (0, 1, 2, 3....). Un saludo

Comment: Entonces debes leer su columna de mysql. La que uses de indice o auto-incremental. Por favor muestra la estructura de tu tabla para ver que columna es la que usas para eso.

Comment: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabla_valores_doc( 
    `Api_` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL , `Password_` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL , `Documento_` BLOB NULL ,
     `Id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));";

Comment: La idea es editarlo en la publicacion jaja. Pero si, tienes una PK que es `Id`, la cual puedes usar para saber la posicion de la fila y asi borrarla.